# How to make UI responsive even clicking loading button

Tags: android, json, android-listview

Can anyone help me out how to make list view responsive even clicking loading button.I am trying with the code below but it crashes when loading is going on & that time if I try to click listview app crashes.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();




        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (i++ < 1000) {

                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                imgvw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        // new Thread();

                                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        View progressBar12 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);
                                        progressBar12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background Fetch",0).show();                               
                                        imgvw.refreshDrawableState();
                                        isrefresh = true;
                                        try {
                                            new InqLis();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Errors are:"+e);
                                        }



                            }   
                        });
                            }


                        });

                        Thread.sleep(300);

                    } 
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                manojAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                manojAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }


        }.start();



    View progressBar12 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);
       progressBar12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    }
```

---

```
02-18 21:17:33.382: E/InputEventReceiver(26835): Exception dispatching input event.
02-18 21:17:33.383: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(16908298, class com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshExpandableListView$InternalExpandableListViewSDK9) with Adapter(class android.widget.ExpandableListConnector)]
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3617)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3429)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7736)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2212)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2218)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7916)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4030)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3909)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3459)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3585)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3486)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3459)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3486)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3459)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5727)
02-18 21:17:33.436: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26835):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:56
```

Comment: That one is logcat error coming @George Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly It looks like you are using an asyncTask.

I would look at the android Developer documentation for proper usage: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

An asyctask has 3 main parts:

1. onPreExecute- runs on UI Thread
2. doInBackground- runs on background Thread
3. onPostExecute- runs on UI Thread

So:
 in onPreExecute show a loading dialog
 in doInBackground do your main work
 in onPostExecute hide the loading dialog and update your UI with the results

This process will give you a responsive and thread-safe solution.(and you will not have to use runnable or sleep threads)

Secondly:

Your error is:
`The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.`

This is likely caused by you sleeping the thread for too long. This causes the contents of the adapter to be changed without `notifyDataSetChanged()` being called.

Conclusion: The most reliable solution is to use the AsyncTask's doInBackground method for your background work.

Here is an example of the proper use of an AsyncTask:

```
    private static class ExampleAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ExampleObject>> {
    private GenericRecycler adapter;

    public ExampleAsync(GenericRecycler theAdapter){
        this.adapter = theAdapter;
    } 

    @Override //runs on main UI Thread
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //make any UI changes here to display while loading
    }



    // runs in a seperate thread
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ExampleObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<ExampleObject> exampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleObject>(10);

        //waiting instead of doing work
        //this is where you should do an http request and create a list of data
        synchronized (this){
            try {
                wait(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return exampleList;
    }

    //this runs on main ui thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ExampleObject> objects){

        adapter.setData(objects);

        //any time that data in adapter is changed, notifydatasetchanged() must be called
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); I am calling but still its taking unfortunatily error.So according to that i have follow that 3 steps or any suggestion @spinster

Comment: The technical reason why you are getting the error: 1.)background ui thread ->2.) Sleep UI Thread -> 3.)Background finishes quickly ->4.) notifydatasetchanged is not called soon enough after the background finishes... This is one of the many reasons why best practice is to use the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks For Giving suggestion, i will try & inform that work or still crashing @spinster